# Big string to nice array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

I need to make big string into a nice array. String itself is list of tags and tag ids. There can be any amount of them. Here is example of the string: `29:funny,30:humor,2:lol` - id:tag_name. Now, I have problem converting it to array - `Array ( [29] => funny [30] => humor  )`. I can get to the part where tags are as so

> Array (
>
> > [0] = Array (
> >
> > > [0] = 29
> > >
> > > [1] = funny
> >
> > )
> >
> > [1] = Array (
> >
> > > [0] = 30
> > >
> > > [1] = humor
> >
> > )
>
> )

I've look at array functions too but seems none of them could help me. 
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to get you going:

```
$str = "29:funny,30:humor,2:lol";
$arr = array();
foreach (explode(',', $str) as $v) {
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $v);
    $arr[$key] = $val;
}
print_r($arr);
/* will output:
Array
(
    [29] => funny
    [30] => humor
    [2] => lol
)
*/
```

You could replace the foreach with an `array_map` for example, but I think it's simpler for you this way.

Here's an example of it working: http://codepad.org/4BpnCiEJ

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode() to do this, though it would take two passes.  The first to split the string into pairings (explode (',', $string)) and the second to split each paring

```
$arr = explode (',', $string);
foreach ($arr as &$pairing)
{
    $pairing = explode (':', $pairing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '29:funny,30:humor,2:lol';
$arr1   = explode(',', $string);
$result = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $element1) {
    $result[]  = explode(':', $element1);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('#([\d]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#', $sString, $aMatches);

// Combine the keys with the values.
$aArray = array_combine($aMatches[1], $aMatches[2]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($aArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [29] => funny
    [30] => humor
    [2] => lol
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$test = '29:funny,30:humor,2:lol';

$tmp_array = explode(',', $test);

$tag_array = ARRAY();

foreach ($tmp_array AS $value) {
    $pair = explode(':', $value);
    $tag_array[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

var_dump($tag_array);

?>
```